# Cron entry for last Saturday of every month

Tags: cron, date

I want to schedule my script for last Saturday of every month.
I have come up with the below:

```
45 23 22-28 * *  test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "4th Saturday"  && sh  /folder/script.sh
```

Is this correct or I need to change it?
I can't test it right now as it will be invoked only on last saturday.
Please advise.

I have the below for last sunday of every month but i can't understand much of it. The first part gives 24 which is sunday and after -eq gives 7 which i don't know what it means:

```
00 17  * * 0 [ $(cal -s | tail -2 | awk '{print $1}') -eq $(date | awk '{print $3}') ] && /folder/script.sh
```

Can I modify the above to get last saturday?

With Romeo's help I was help to come up with the below answer:

```
00 17 * * 6 [ $(cal -s | tail -2 | awk '{print $7}') -eq $(date | awk '{print $3}') ] && /folder/script.sh
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your logic will not work. Month can have last Saturday to be on 29 or 30 or 31. For this reason the best way to do the check is to run it every Saturday and check in script if this is in last 7 days in month:

```
45 23 * * 6  sh  /folder/script.sh
```

and add in your script (here assuming the GNU implementation of `date`) something like:

```
if [ "$(date -d "+7 day" +%m)" -eq "$(date +%m)" ]
then echo "This is not one of last 7 days in month.";exit
fi
<rest of your script>
```

About your line in cron you should edit it to start like this:

```
00 17  * * 6
```

(6 means Saturday, 0 or 7 mean Sunday)

Comment: What if i extend the date range from 22-28 to 22-31?
Because if have similar script for 3rd friday of every month with range 15-21 and -eq 5 and that works fine.

Comment: @user3901666, in interval 22-31 you may have more than one Saturday. Check your calendar for November this year. And for last Saturday its different because you can have 5 Saturdays in month

Comment: I have the cron for last sunday of each month (posted in the description), But i don't know how its works. Can i modify it to get the cron for saturday?

Comment: The problem is I can't modify my script as it is a generic script which works for other schedules as well.

Comment: @user3901666, you can always create a copy of this script and edit it :)

Comment: Yes i can edit it but i won't be able to test it and since i can't modify my final script to add the part of the code you sent , i am looking for the option with awk which has been already implemented for last sunday of every month.

Comment: @user3901666, check my edited answer

Comment: And what about this part "$(cal -s | tail -2 | awk '{print $1}') -eq $(date | awk '{print $3}') " ,, will it remain same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100779/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-user3901666).

Comment: Updated the answer with your help. Thanks u so much!!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use the Dillon Crontab (which I believe it is better, includes more features, and supplies also anacron), then you have the option of:

> If you specify both a day in the month and a day of week, it will be interpreted as the Nth such day in the month.

```
45 23 5 * 6  /path/script.sh
```

> To request the last Monday, etc. in a month, ask for the "5th" one. This will always match the last Monday, etc., even if there are only four Mondays in the month

Hopefully you and others can use this answer for future consultation.

---

References:

- https://github.com/dubiousjim/dcron/blob/master/crontab.markdown
- https://itectec.com/unixlinux/is-posix-wrong-about-crontab-with-non-asterisk-month-and-day-of-week/
- http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html

Answer (score 1):

While the rest of the answers are framed in the way you asked the question (via cronjob).

It's important to note this is why systemd timers exist. They have more robust scheduling.

Instead of a cronjob, you create a systemd service and matching timer.

Use OnCalendar in timer

```
OnCalendar=Sat *-*~07/1 23:45:00
```

or more verbosely...

```
OnCalendar=Sat *-1,3,5,7,8,10,12-25..31 23:45:00
OnCalendar=Sat *-4,6,9,11-24..30 23:45:00
OnCalendar=Sat *-2-22..29 23:45:00
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timers

https://documentation.suse.com/smart/linux/html/task-create-systemd-timers/index.html#id-1.5

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
45 23 */25,*/26,*/27,*/28,*/29,*/30,*/31 * SAT
```

I have not tried this, but [Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#45_23_*/25,*/26,*/27,*/28,*/29,*/30,*/31_*_SAT) says it's possible:

[image]

Comment: For a 30-day month, last Saturday could be the 24th (and if include 24, two Saturdays could match for 31-day months), so it doesn't match last saturday for every month.

Comment: @thanasisp you are right. I was using similar script for Sundays and in September it would skip without 24th being used. With 24th being used then it would do it two times a month in some months. Well, if the task is not critical, its an ok solution - which is the case for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
00 01 * * 6 [ $(date +\%d) -gt $(date \-d "-$(date +\%d) days month -7 days" +\%d) ] && /run/my/script
```

$(date +%d) is current day

$(date -d "-$(date +%d) days month -7 days" +%d) is "minus this months days  (so previous month's last day) plus a month, minus 7 days."

So running on 14th Feb 2023 we get:

```
[ 14 -gt 21 ] && /run/my/script
```

So it wont run.

Get it to check on day 6 to run it every Saturday at the time you want.