# cron expression to get the last Saturday of the month

Tags: cron

How I can have a cron expression which runs a scheduled job  **every last Saturday** of the month at 5PM IST?

Comment: Do you want to run it at 17:00:00 +05:30 (India Standard Time) even if the system's cron daemon is not configured to be in that timezone?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I would chose the US/Eastern Timezone to sync with the 5PM IST

Comment: @RomeoNinov : No. I cannot use any additional configuration to get the last saturday of the month.

Comment: @BindumaliniKK What do you mean by your last comment?

Comment: @Kusalananda As per this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550835/cron-entry-for-last-saturday ,I cannot use another file to get the last saturday.

Comment: You can schedule an `if` statement...

Comment: I can only add cron expression.

Comment: @BindumaliniKK, as suggested add all this as one line (with `if` and so on)

Comment: I am using this expression on a tool where I can just add the expression and the timezone. I cannot add anything like a script/if etc. nor I can modify the existing job.

Comment: Please join this : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128442/cron-to-get-the-last-saturday-of-the-month